# Re-arrange the order of text in a textarea using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textarea with this content as shown

```
<textarea id="textfield"><img src="smile.png alt=":)"/>Hi</textarea>
```

I am using the below js code to filter the content of the textarea **img alt** value and the **Hi** as shown to get a result like this **:) Hi** but I want it to be arranged to this order **Hi :)** using the below snippet

```
$scope.performaction = function () {
//get the value of the textarea
        var textarea = angular.element('#textfield').val();
        textareaValue = textarea;
        var altValues = [];
    while (true) {
        var altValueMatch = textareaValue.match(/\<img.*?alt=(\"|\')(.*?)\1.*?\>/),
            altValue = (Array.isArray(altValueMatch) && typeof altValueMatch[2] === "string")
                ? altValueMatch[2]
                : null;

        if (altValue !== null) {
            altValues.push(altValue);
        } else {
            break;
        }
        textareaValue = textareaValue.replace(/\<img.*?\>/, "").trim();
    }
var concatenated = [altValues, textareaValue].join(" ");
                concatenated.replace(/&nbsp;|,/g,'');
    //assign the value to the second textarea of ng-model="content"
                $scope.content = concatenated;

            };
```

How do I use the above js code to rearrange the textarea value to something like this **Hi :)** after filtering using angularjs. In other words, let the alt value come last.

Answer (score 0):

In your js, change the sequence of concatenating the content, include textareavalue first and then alternate values

```
var concatenated = [textareaValue, altValues].join(" ");
concatenated.replace(/&nbsp;|,/g,'');
//assign the value to the second textarea of ng-model="content"
$scope.content = concatenated;
```

Comment: I want something dynamic

Answer (score 0):

you can always `$watch` the `alt` attribute in a directive like so

js:

```
 app.directive('altChange',function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'a',
        link: function(scope,elem,attr){
           scope.$watch(function(){return elem.val()},function(value){
              var textarea = value;
        textareaValue = textarea;
        var altValues = [];
    while (true) {
        var altValueMatch = textareaValue.match(/\<img.*?alt=(\"|\')(.*?)\1.*?\>/),
            altValue = (Array.isArray(altValueMatch) && typeof altValueMatch[2] === "string")
                ? altValueMatch[2]
                : null;

        if (altValue !== null) {
            altValues.push(altValue);
        } else {
            break;
        }
        textareaValue = textareaValue.replace(/\<img.*?\>/, "").trim();
    }
var concatenated = [altValues, textareaValue].join(" ");
                concatenated.replace(/&nbsp;|,/g,'');
    //assign the value to the second textarea of ng-model="content"
                $scope.content = concatenated;
           })
        }
      }
    })
```

html:

```
<textarea alt-change id="textfield"><img src="smile.png alt=":)"/>Hi</textarea>
```

**explanation**

by creating a directive that listen to the `element.val()` now every time the value is been change the angular `digest` system will call to the function  that pass to the `$watch` function

another point is that the default `scope` property is `scope:false` and therefore the `$scope.content` will bubule your controller `$scope`

Comment: Your function contains link function contains three argument. Please post a complete snippet

Comment: Must add this return :{

Comment: It is seeing the : as unexpected and as a result the code does not compile

Comment: yes you must add this return, this is how angular directive works. and i fix the issue of the `:`